# why would you slice an array from beginning to end?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

I found the following pattern in an example code from [Ch 11 of Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/11_language.html):

```
array.slice(0, array.length - 1)
```

My question is **why would you slice an array from it's beginning to its end?**

Here is the example code where I found that pattern.  See the declaration of `argNames` right in the middle (I included an `-->` at the line in question:

```
specialForms["fun"] = function(args, env) {
  if (!args.length)
    throw new SyntaxError("Functions need a body");
  function name(expr) {
    if (expr.type != "word")
      throw new SyntaxError("Arg names must be words");
    return expr.name;
  }
  -->var argNames = args.slice(0, args.length - 1).map(name);
  var body = args[args.length - 1];

  return function() {
    if (arguments.length != argNames.length)
      throw new TypeError("Wrong number of arguments");
    var localEnv = Object.create(env);
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
      localEnv[argNames[i]] = arguments[i];
    return evaluate(body, localEnv);
  };
};
```

Comment: It basically just returns a copy of the array. In this case it doesn't seem necessary as `map` returns a new array anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.slice` method copies/clones the array. You normally would do this if you do not want to modify the original array.  Looking at your example, though, I don't think you even need to use the .slice cloning method, because `.map` already returns a new array.

[Here is a link to more information about cloning arrays](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array).